# Do I need to reset a stream(C#) back to the start if I pass stream into method as Pass Value-Type Parameter method

Tags: c#

I have seen a couple of the example on internet stated that I have to reset the stream by

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

However, if I pass the stream into a method as

```
public static bool ValidateStreamLine(Stream stream)
```

Do I have to still reset the stream?

Understand that on usual case if I pass in int, string, float or any other general variable type as

```
public static bool ValidateInt(int i)
```

the value of int i would not change.

Would that be any difference of the nature of Pass-by Value method on how the method react to stream?

Comment: Yes. The stream is the access method, not the content. And you can't pass it by value anyway, it's a reference type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Does that mean I can do reset in ValidateStreamLine method and it will work as well?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm picky but it is passed by value, it's a reference type passed by value

Comment: There's no generic answer to this question. Quite apart from the fact that *some streams cannot be reset*, you also need to *read the documentation* for any method that accepts a `Stream` parameter, to determine what it's requirements and expectations are.

Comment: @vc74 to someone coming from a  C++ background this leads to more confusion. Yes, a reference to the object is passed by value, but it's still a reference to the object, not the object itself. In this case, even the `byref` keyword wouldn't change the behaviour.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Passing it by reference would absolutely change the behavior.  It would allow for the mutation of the variable.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What do you mean, you can not pass it by value? Of course you can, that is the default way *any* argument is passed in C#. That the type is a reference type or a value type has absolutely nothing to do with *how* you pass an argument in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how arguments are passed in C#. By default, all arguments are passed by *value* in C#. In order to pass them by *reference* you need to use a special keyword: `ref` or `out` the latter being normally used when the argument is used as a second output of a given method. (See `int.TryPase` for example).

The important thing to understand here is that arguments passed by value behave quite diferently if the type of the argument is a reference type or a value type. This is where you seem to be confused.

To understand how it all works, make sure you are clear on the following:

1. Variables hold *values*.
2. The *value* of a variable whose type is a *value type*, *is the value type's instance itself*:

   ```
   int i = 1 // i holds the value 1
   ```
3. The *value* of a variable whose type is a *reference type is not the instance of said type*. The value is the *memory address where that instance lives*.

   ```
   string s = "Hello!" // s does not hold "Hello!" it holds a number that points to a place in memory where the string "Hello!" lives.
   ```

So, now that we are clear on that, what happens when you pass arguments by value (C#'s default)? What happens is that a *copy of the variable is made and the copy is passed to the method*.

If the type is a reference type, what is really copied and passed to the method is the value stored in the variable. And what is that? The memory address where the object referenced by the variable lives. So you see what happens? Both the original variable and the copied variable *both point to the same object*:

```
public class Foo
{
    var frobbed = false;
    public bool Frobbed { get { return frobbed; } }
    public void Frob() { frobbed = true; }
}

void Frob(Foo foo) { foo.Frob(); }
var myFoo = new Foo();
Frob(myFoo);
Console.WriteLine(myFoo.Frobbed); //Outputs True! Why? Because myFoo and foo both point to the same object! The value of both variables (memory address) is the same!
```

If the type is a value type, the value itself of the value type is copied and handed to the method so there is no way the method can modify the value type stored in the original variable.

```
public void Increment(int i) { i = i + 1; }

var myInt = 1;
Increment(myInt);
Console.WriteLine(myInt); //Outputs 1, not 2. Why? i holds its own copy of 1, it knows nothing about the copy of 1 stored in myInt.
```

Things change when you pass arguments by reference. Now, the argument passed to the method is not a copy, its the original variable itself. A logical question follows; does this actually change anything in how reference types behave? The answer is yes, quite a lot:

```
public void ByValueCall(string s)
{
    s = "Goodbye";
}

public void ByReferenceCall(ref string s)
{
    s = "Goodbye";
}

var myString = "Hello!";
Console.WriteLine(ByValueCall(myString )); //outputs "Hello!"
Console.WriteLine(ByValueCall(myString )); //outputs "Goodbye!"
```

This behavior is identical with value types too. What is happening here?

When you pass an argument by value, the method gets a copy of the variable; therefore *assigning a new value to the argument is really just assigning a new value to the copy*; the original variable at the callsite doesn't care that you change the value of it's copy, be it a value type or a reference type. It will keep holding the value it always had.

When passing an argument by reference, you are not passing a copy, you are passing the variable itself. In that case assigning a new value to the variable will persist at the callsite. A canonical example is the following swap method:

```
public void Swap(ref int a, ref int b)
{
    var temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

var i1 = 1;
var i2 = 2;
Swap(ref i1, ref i2);
var b = i1 == 2; //true
b = i2 == 1; //true
```

So after all of this, you should understand why the following behaves the way it does:

```
public ResetStream(Stream stream)
{
   stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
}

var myStream = new ...
myStream.Read(bytes, 0, 1024);
ResetStream(myStream);
var isAtOrigin = myStream.Position == 0; //Returns true!
```

Comment: @BenKnoble Lol, I completely forgot about that. Fixed, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation :) There's an additional question on that. Besides stream, string type, what are the other type that behave similar? Is there a complete list for this?

Comment: @SimonLoh The vast majority are reference types. The rule is simple: *structs* are *value types* and a *classes* are *reference types*. If you are not sure, just inspect the type's definition.